# Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' when trying to create new project

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

Can any one please help me solve this issue?

> Errors occurred during the build.
>   Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'SAD_spring_maven_restful'.
>   Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
>   Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6

Comment: This means your pom does not have all requisite entries. You are missing entry for "maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved", but you are using it somewhere

Comment: where is this pom file? i am getting this error when i try to create new maven project

Comment: What is the complete command line you run?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and I have a similar error. When I try to create the new marven project I get the error `Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6` if I select maven-achetype-webapp